# How many such $k$-cycles $C=v_0v_1\dots v_{k-1}v_0$ are there?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In [Diestel's *Graph Theory*](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ebilley/classes/562.winter.2018/articles/GraphTheory.pdf), the proof of page 298 Lemma 11.1.5:

> How many such cycles $C=v_0\dots v_{k-1}v_0$ are there?

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n$ vertices, my question is that how many such $k$-cycles $C=v_0v_1\dots v_{k－1} v_0$ are there?

Clearly, there are sequences $(n)_k:=n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$ of distinct vertices in $V$. But why the number of such $k-$cycles is $(n)_k/2k$?

[image]

Comment: I don't think what you want to prove is true. For one, $v_0$ could very well be an isolated vertex in which case no such cycle exists.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis I have added my motivation of my question. Does the sentence in red color part mean my question?

Comment: Don't usevimages to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for why](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the correct count for the number of $k$-cycles in the complete graph $K_n$.  For each such sequence of distinct vertices, rotating the sequence preserves the cycle, as does reversing the sequence.  There are therefore $2k$ members of each equivalence class, yielding $(n)_k/(2k)$ equivalence classes ($k$-cycles).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added my question. Can you please see it again? I am confused the part in red color in the proof. So I asked my question before.

Comment: Do you see that reversing the sequence of vertices yields the same cycle (same set of edges)? That accounts for the factor of $2$. Similarly, the $k$ different rotations of the sequence yield the same cycle, accounting for the factor of $k$.

Comment: Yes. But the author did not assume $k$-cycles in a complete graph, right? Is still the number of such cycles $(n)_k/(2k)$?

Comment: Also, if $C=v_0 v_1\dots v_{k-1}$, then rotating the sequence preserves the cycle $v_1v_2\dots v_{k-1}v_0$ and so on. I think there are $k$ members in this rotating. Where do I miss another $k$ member?

Comment: Reversing and rotating are independent operations, so you multiply $2$ and $k$.

Comment: To see the idea, I recommend writing out the $3!=6$ sequences for $n=3$ and $k=3$ and then observing that they all yield the same cycle.

Comment: No, I am confused about your first sentence in the answer. That is the correct count for the number of k-cycles in the complete graph $K_n$. But in the proof on this Lemma 11.1.5. This is not the complete graph.

Comment: The random graph $\mathcal{G}(n,p)$ is based on selecting each edge of the complete graph $K_n$ independently with probability $p$.